# Why is adMob throwing these null pointer exceptions in Android?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, admob

So I have the Android app complete and everything, then I downloaded the SDK from adMob and integrated it in the app. After integrating the ads, I noticed that this exception kept showing up in the console every time I ran the app.

```
[2011-09-01 22:25:21 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:572)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:671)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

[2011-09-01 22:25:21 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:572)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:671)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

The app doesn't crash or anything, and the ads are showing just fine and working properly, but this exception keeps showing up. Why? How can I get rid of it? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Could you add the part of the source code throwing the null pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was a simple log AdMob executed from within its code. Nothing out of the ordinary.